# Check if space is in a string

Tags: python, string

```
' ' in word == True
```

I'm writing a program that checks whether the string is a single word. Why doesn't this work and is there any better way to check if a string has no spaces/is a single word..

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get syntax error? Do you get no errors at all?

Comment: Also, it's ok to paste code in your comment, just make sure you format it.

Comment: *Never* use `expression == True` to test for truth. Just use `expression`!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`==` takes precedence over `in`, so you're actually testing `word == True`.

```
>>> w = 'ab c'
>>> ' ' in w == True
1: False
>>> (' ' in w) == True
2: True
```

But you don't need `== True` at all. `if` requires [something that evalutes to True or False] and `' ' in word` will evalute to true or false. So, `if ' ' in word: ...` is just fine:

```
>>> ' ' in w
3: True
```

Comment: It won't match all kinds of spaces : \n, \r, ' ', ... If he needs to match them, it's better to use re module, with the match method on \s. It will do a better tokenizer.

Comment: Programming pet peeve: `... == True` or `... != False`, or any variant thereof.

Comment: Jukka Suomela's explanation is a little more correct than mine, by the way. By my explanation, you'd be testing `word==True` then `' ' in True`, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 25):

Write `if " " in word:` instead of `if " " in word == True:`.

Explanation:

- In Python, for example `a < b < c` is equivalent to `(a < b) and (b < c)`.
- The same holds for any chain of comparison operators, which include `in`!
- Therefore `' ' in w == True` is equivalent to `(' ' in w) and (w == True)` which is *not* what you want.

Comment: Wow. I knew that `<` and `==` worked the way you described, but I didn't realize `in` did, too. I had assumed combining them would be seen as `a in (b == c)` or `(a in b) == c`. To see that it's really interpreted as Jukka says, you can try `'a' in 'abc' == 'abc'`. It's `True`, but it would be `False` if it were interpreted in either of the other ways I suggested.

Answer (score 16):

There are a lot of ways to do that :

```
t = s.split(" ")
if len(t) > 1:
  print "several tokens"
```

To be sure it matches every kind of space, you can use re module :

```
import re
if re.search(r"\s", your_string):
  print "several words"
```

Comment: You don't need regex to check for every kind of space, simply omit the `" "` you are passing to `s.split()`, as the default includes all whitespace: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 4):

You can try this, and if it will find any space it will return the position where the first space is.

```
if mystring.find(' ') != -1:
    print True
else:
    print False
```

Comment: `mystring.find(' ') != -1` **is** boolean.

Comment: I.e., this can be shortened to `print mystring.find(' ') != -1`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 're' module in Python 3.
If you indeed do, use this:

```
re.search('\s', word)
```

This should return either 'true' if there's a match, or 'false' if there isn't any.

Comment: This is not equivalent (also matches `\t\n\r\f\v` next to normal spaces) and introduces a *lot* of overhead. A quick check revealed `48.5ns` for `" " in word` versus `873ns` for `re.search("\s", word)`, more than one order of magnitude slower. The regex should only be used for genuinely more complex tasks.

Comment: Its more important to actually perform the action that OP wants. In this case 900ns or 50ns is most likely not relevant unless they are parsing a whole book word-per-word compared to not detecting if a string contains whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can say `word.strip(" ")` to remove any leading/trailing spaces from the string - you should do that before your `if` statement. That way if someone enters input such as `" test "` your program will still work.

That said, `if " " in word:` will determine if a string contains any spaces. If that does not working, can you please provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned whitespace in general, rather than just spaces. I stumbled upon a solution with `isidentifier`. Per W3 schools:

> A string is considered a valid identifier if it only contains alphanumeric letters (a-z) and (0-9), or underscores (_). A valid identifier cannot start with a number, or contain any spaces.

So, if this matches your requirements, isidentifier is quick and easy to use.

Somebody mentioned efficiency of regex, and I was curious:

```py
import timeit

setup='import re; rs="\s"; rc=re.compile(rs); s="applebananacanteloupe"'
stm1='re.search(rs,s)'
stm2='re.search(rc,s)'
stm3='" " in s'
stm4='s.isidentifier()'

timeit.repeat(stm1,setup)
# result: [0.9235025509842671, 0.8889087940042373, 0.8771460619755089, 0.8753634429886006, 1.173506731982343]

timeit.repeat(stm2,setup)
# results: [1.160843407997163, 1.1500899779784959, 1.1857644470001105, 1.1485740720236208, 1.2856045850203373]
# compiled slower than uncompiled? Hmm, I don't get regex...

timeit.repeat(stm3,setup)
# [0.039073383988579735, 0.03403249100665562, 0.03481135700712912, 0.034628107998287305, 0.03392893000273034]

timeit.repeat(stm4,setup)
# [0.08866660299827345, 0.09206177099258639, 0.08418851799797267, 0.08478381999884732, 0.09471498697530478]
```

So, `isidentifier` is almost as fast as `in`, and 10x faster than regex. Note that there is technically no guarantee that python's idea of what an identifier is won't change - but it's also likely that if it did, your code would need some rework anyway.

Comment: If you change `stm2` to be `stm2='rc.search(s)'` you will notice that the compiled query is faster than the uncompiles query, it's 2X to 4X faster on my machine than the uncompiled version.

Answer (score 0):

```
word = ' '
while True:
    if ' ' in word:
        word = raw_input("Please enter a single word: ")
    else:
        print "Thanks"
        break
```

This is more idiomatic python - comparison against True or False is not necessary - just use the value returned by the expression `' ' in word`.

Also, you don't need to use pastebin for such a small snippet of code - just copy the code into your post and use the little 1s and 0s button to make your code look like code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
word = raw_input("Please enter a single word : ")
while True:
    if " " in word:
        word = raw_input("Please enter a single word : ")
    else:
        print "Thanks"
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# The following would be a very simple solution.

print("")
string = input("Enter your string :")
noofspacesinstring = 0
for counter in string:
    if counter == " ":
       noofspacesinstring += 1
if noofspacesinstring == 0:
   message = "Your string is a single word" 
else:
   message = "Your string is not a single word"
print("")   
print(message)   
print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def word_in(s):
   return " " not in s
```

Comment: maybe consider telling the author of the question why his solution does not work and why you think yours is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can see whether the output of the following code is 0 or not.

```
'import re
x='  beer   '
len(re.findall('\s', x))
```