# Input is null, empty

Tags: python

I have code that checks if there's any space or is it just empty. I tried remaking the =, "", '',  ==. But I didn't succeed. What's the problem? When I'm entering the password its always says the error, that I have in print function.

```
while True:
    password = getpass.getpass("~ Please pick a password, for user - {n}\n".format(n=name))
    fontas = " "
    fontas2 = ' '
    if fontas and fontas2 in password:
        print("~ Password can't contain a spaces!\n")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

EDIT*
I'm adding a GIF. Which Shows you how this works now, when i changed a code a bit.

First try I'm trying to make a space, after I'm not typing anything, And the last time i put normal keyword - ffawt

*I Cannot add GIF Files, So I'm uploading link in Gyazo platform.

LINK - [enter link description here](https://gyazo.com/afd9566c44566f1978ef4bf76cd64534)

Comment: I don't understand the point of `if fontas`. The value can't change

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. Firstly there's no difference between `" "` and `' '`. Secondly, if there was, it should be an `or ` combination, not `and`. Thirdly you aren't checking if both values are in the password with that, which should be `fontas in password and fontas2 in password`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if space is in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301395/check-if-space-is-in-a-string)

Comment: If password would be - " Rauna51" it would be error because of space right? but What if input is empty? - "" Blank? I use the Fontas = '' Sorry for space beetwhen ' ' in the code.

Comment: There's an empty string in **every** string, empty or not: `"" in ""`, `"" in "password"`, `"" in "pass word"` are all true.

Comment: No, when i did if ' ' in password: It doesn't help, when i don't type anything inside, it just continues after pressing enter, and when making a space, it shows the error

Comment: Why doesn't it help you are confusing empty string with space.

Comment: We don't *want* GIFs, or links; put a [mcve] **in the question**, as correctly formatted code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
while True:
    Password = input('Enter a password: ')
    if " " in Password or len(Password) == 0:
        print("~ Password can't contain a spaces!")
        continue

    #if 'if' statement evaluates to True
    print(Password)
    break
```

Edit:

Although this will 'Get the job done', There are other ways to evaluate if a string is empty in python!

An empty string will evaluate to a boolean value (False):

```
Password = ""
if not Password:
      print("isempty")
>>> isempty
```

That being said, The code above can be refactored as:

```
while True:
      Password = input('Enter a password: ')
      #Make 'falsy' evaluation of password
      if not Password or " " in Password:
          print("~ Password can't contain a spaces!")
          continue

     #if 'if' statement evaluates to True
      print(Password)
      break
```

Comment: `len(Password) == 0` isn't a very nice check for an empty string, and the resulting error message doesn't actually match the problem with the input.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The print message does not match 100% with the logic but he wanted a block that: checks if there's any space ` if " " in Password` in the password string, is just empty `len(Password) == 0`. How would you update this block

Comment: You did not explian to OP what is wrong with his code. You should not compute the length to check for emptiness. I would not be surprised if this is getting downvoted

Comment: @BlueSheepToken, Thanks for bringing this to my attention :)! I have made some edits to predicate string emptiness logic on Falsy evaluation rather than string length. This should handle the edge cases more smoothly

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a regular expression. A regular Expression can check for `" "` in strings.E.g.

```
fontas = password.match(' ')
if fontas:
    print('Match found: ', fontas.group())
else:
    print('No match')
```

Check the docs for more information.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Why would that be necessary? `fontas2 in password` is fine, and more efficient than a regex, it's everything else that's the problem.

Comment: Doesn't help at all.

Comment: Obviously it's not, otherwise you wouldnt be running into this kind of issue. If you are handling passwords you probably want to check for more than just spaces, so a Regular Expression would be very useful anyways.

Answer (score 0):

`fontas` and `fontas2` are the same, you can just do

```
if ' ' in password:
    print("~ Password can't contain a spaces!\n")
    # ...
```

A full example:

```
import getpass

# ...

name = 'Alex' # considering a user called Alex

while True:
    password = getpass.getpass(
        "~ Please pick a password, for user - {n}\n".format(n=name))
    fontas = " "
    if fontas in password:
        print("~ Password can't contain a spaces!\n")
        continue
    elif not password:
        print("~ Password can't be empty!\n")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: You see, you did a code, which see's if there's any space, but it won't check if the code is null, empty.

Comment: If you want to check if no password has been provided, check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
if password and (" " in password):
    print("BAD")
else
    print("GOOD")
```

it first check if there is a password at all, then check if there is a space

Comment: There's no point in the first part of that condition; if it's an empty string, it definitely won't contain a space!

Comment: Don't help, well I don't understand what's the problem behind these codes.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the provided string is empty, or contains any spaces do this

```
while True:

    password = getpass.getpass("~ Please pick a password, for user {n}\n".format(n=name))
    fontas = " "
    if fontas in password:
        print("~ Password can't contain a spaces!\n")
        continue
    elif password == '':
        print("~ Password cannot be empty!\n")
        continue
    else:
        break
```