# Cheking if a string contains a space or not

Tags: python, string, spaces

Trying to get python to return that a string contains ONLY alphabetic letters AND not spaces .

def valide(name):

```
for i in range(0,len(name)):
    if name[i] == " ":
        print("error, no spaces allowed!")
        break
while True:
    nam = input("give us the name: ")
    valide(nam)
```

It's like an login system that does not allow the name to have sapce
here i want if the string contains a space then return to getting another name and rechecking the condition.

i want the user re-enter another name to re-check if it contains a space

Comment: Ok, what's wrong with your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if space is in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301395/check-if-space-is-in-a-string)

Comment: @Austin i want the user re-enter another name to re-check if it contains a space

Comment: @AdibAkkari You have a `while True` block, so it will ask for another one.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to use the statement `(' ' in nam) == True` will return `True` if the string contains a space.

Hence, the code is simplified to:

```py
while True:
    nam = input("give us the name: ")
    if (' ' in nam):
        print("error, no space allowed!")
```

Comment: FYI, `' ' in nam` itself returns true or false.

Comment: @Austin Ah right, that is more consistent with PEP8 too. Thanks!

Comment: @tripleee I have edited it a couple of minutes before your comment. I wonder why it still shows the old code.

Answer (score 0):

```py
while True:
    nam = input("give us the name: ")
    if ' ' in nam:
        print("error, no space allowed!")
    else:
        print("no spaced detected")
```